# Where is cudaMemcpySymbolToSymbol?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to copy the contents of one symbol to another, on the same device.  I'm not finding any support for this.

```
__device__ int someData;
__constant__ int someConst;
```

;

```
int temp;
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&temp,"someConst",sizeof(int),0,cudaMemcpyFromHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpyToSymbol("someData",&temp,sizeof(int),0,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

or

```
int *tmp
cudaMalloc((void**)tmp,sizeof(int);
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(tmp,"someConst",sizeof(int),0,cudMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(toSymbol("someData",tmp,sizeof(int),0,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
cudaFree(tmp);
```

Is there a simpler way to copy from symbol to symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a symbol to symbol API call. If you are going to do this more than once, the best way is probably something like this in setup code:

```
__device__ int someData;
__constant__ int someConst;

int * _D, * _C;
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&_D, someData);
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&_C, someConst);
```

which gets you the address of both symbols in GPU memory, and then use `cudaMemcpy` instead, so:

```
cudaMemcpy(_C, _D, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

Doing it this way removes the symbol look up overhead and reduces the operation to a device to device copy call.